# Constructor Injection using Parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I have the following bean with parameterized constructor:

```
@Component
public class AuthHelper{
    @Autowired
    private AuthClient gmailClient;
    @Autowired
    private AuthClient yahooClient;

    private AuthClient client;

    public AuthHelper client(String option) {
        if(option.equals("gmail")) this.client=gmailClient;
        if(option.equals("yahoo")) this.client=yahooClient;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean authLogic(String uid, String pass) {
        return client.authorize(uid,pass);
    }

}
```

Could you please help to autowire the above bean:

I am stuck while I call the above bean in the below service,

```
@Service
public class AuthService{
    @Autowired
    public AuthHelper authHelper;

    public boolean authenticate(String uid, String pass){
        return authHelper.client("gmail").authLogic(uid, pass);
    }

}
```

Please suggest... I want the helper class should use the bean based on the parameter that I pass from the service.

After Modification:
The above example is working fine. Please suggest if there is any issue in this implementation...

Comment: where is the AuthHelper class injection? How can the class use the consturctor?

Comment: i think configuration is what you need, you can autowire(inject) (option)configuration here.

Comment: The current logic is working fine now. Please suggest if this implementation is not good or will cause issue anywhere. Will it set globally(for others user who is trying for yahoo in parellel) while I set like `authHelper.client("gmail").authLogic(uid, pass)`?

Comment: i have two comments 1. .client("gmail") usually should be a static method(factory pattern, `client` can be renamed to `of`) 2. you still have to hardcode a type string, which should be automatically injected and got from current http context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the better approach would be to have a AuthHelperFactory which should provide the AuthHelper bean with appropriate client as per input.

```
public class AuthHelper{

private AuthClient client;

public AuthHelper (AuthClient client) {
    this.client = client;
}

public boolean authLogic(String uid, String pass) {
    return this.client.authorize(uid,pass);
}

}

@Component
public class AuthHelperFactory {
  @Autowired
  private AuthClient gmailClient;
  @Autowired
  private AuthClient yahooClient;

  public AuthHelper getAuthHelper(String option) {
     if(option.equals("gmail")){
        return new AuthHelper(gmailClient);
     } else if (option.equals("yahoo")){
        return new AuthHelper(yahooClient); 
     }
  }
 }
```

In the AuthService, you need to call the factory method in  authenticate method.

```
return authHelperFactory.getAuthHelper("gmail").authLogic(uid, pass);
```

Comment: Could you please give sample snippet?